# Rg.Plugins.Popup - app crashes on ios when open popup repeatedly

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, popup

Hello I am developing a Xamarin Forms app, I have use Rg.Plugins.Popup plugins. this plugin working fine on android but app crashes on ios as i repeatedly open and close popup...

Comment: Could you show some codes ? I test the demo on ios,but could not reproduce the issue.

Comment: Just create a demo app with the plugin install and try opening and closing a popup at a rapid rate and it will crash.

Answer (score -1):

I was having same problem in my project in my case it was due to when i open multiple times at some point popup comes and suddenly goes away and when i next time open the pop up and close it app get crashed after debugging the issue i found that when suddenly the popup appeared and closed its instance was yet present in the popup stack and when i click on close popup it tried to close popup which was on the stack but never exists as it was auto closed

after research at that time i found that it was a bug of Rg.popup and got it resolved by upgrading my nuget to latest

> Rg.Plugins.Popup 1.2.0223

if you are facing same issue in this case also just upgrade to mentioned version there are much chances of getting your issue resolved

Comment: I am already using the latest version. This doesn't help me at all

Comment: this didn't help me((